# Swift CoreData, Problems fetching all child Entities

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a iOS app that uses CoreData. I have three Entities.

1. Game - Abstract Entity
2. SkinsGame - A child of Game Entity
3. NassauGame - A child of Game Entity

I inject a context with an instance of Skins and Nassau into one of my previews. If I fetch using the code `@FetchRequest(entity: Game.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var activeGames: FetchedResults<Game>`

If I run the preview in the canvas, I get the exception "NSInvalidArgumentException. Reason: executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.."

The only way I can get this fetch request to work is if I create an instance of Game and inject it into my preview which I thought would throw some sort of error since I declared it as abstract.

It seems as though it throws this because there are no Game Entities. Though if I change my fetch request to something like `@FetchRequest(entity: SkinsGame.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var activeGames: FetchedResults<Game>` it works just fine.

I thought by giving the entity descriptor Game to the FetchRequest, it would fetch all Entities that are children to parent. If this cant be done, then what is the point in having Entity inheritance? I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You have misunderstood the purpose of the abstract entity. It lets you specify a set of attributes that can then be adopted by other entities, as you have done. It doesn't result in all of the entities being stored in the same "table". You still need to retrieve the specific entity type you want.  What is the difference (in structure) between a `Game` and a `SkinsGame` and a `NassauGame`? You may be better off defining a single `Game` entity with a `type` attribute.

Comment: At least in other programming languages, abstract means that it is an object or data structure in that it cant have an instance of itself. You say "It lets you specify a set of attributes that can be adopted by other entities" but this is true even if you don't specify the Game Entity as abstract. The SkinsGame and NassauGame will have different attributes without listing all of them. If I make a type attribute in Game, am I able to give it a generic type? I would like to use inheritance over some sort of composition.

Comment: Yes abstract entities are used for inheritance and you never create an instance of the abstract entity itself. While core data is an object persistence system and has inheritance and abstract object concepts it doesn't support polymorphism at the persistent store layer. You need to retrieve specific entity types from your store. Through the use of inheritance and abstraction you can use polymorphic concepts with the retrieved entity; e.g. pass a retrieved entity to a function that expects a `Game` regardless of the concrete type